# A quick question on probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

> Consider the following cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ for $x \in [0, 2]$
>
> Figure is: [image: here.]
>
> a. what's density function $f(x)$ corresponding to this $F(x)$.
>
> b. whether a random variable with this distribution has positive or negative expectation? why?
>
> c. Compute the probability of the event: $A = \lbrace\omega: X(\omega) \in (0.6, 0.65]\rbrace$.
>
> [image: Figure] continued for part c.

---

From my understanding, probability density function $f(x)$ is the derivative of $F(x)$.

So,

(a) $f(x) = \begin{cases}
 1 &\text{when}&\quad 0 ≤ x < 0.5; 
 \\ 0&\text{when}&0.5 ≤ x < 1.5; 
 \\1&\text{when}&1.5 ≤ x < 2; \end{cases}$

since $F(x)$ for $x \in [0, 2]$, so we only conside $[0, 2]$ for $f(x)$ too.

(b) Since $\Bbb E(x) = \sum_x f(x)\cdot p(x)$,  $f(x)\geq 0, 0\leq p(x)\leq 1$,  Hence, I guess Expectation must be positive?

(c) I've just lost here. How could we calculate the specific event of $X(\omega) \in (0.6, 0.65]$, when we have PDF or CDF?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: (a) yes. (b) what is $p(x)$? How could a sum be meaningful here? (c) Hint: $Pr(X \le b) = F(b)$.

Comment: (b) That is indeed *not* the fomula for expectation of a *continuous* random variable with density function $f(x)$.

Comment: c) if you have the CDF then the probability in question is just $F(.65)-F(.6)$. d) A function is a CDF if and only if it is non-decreasing, right-continuous and tends to 0 as $x$ escapes to negative infinity and to 1 as $x$ escapes to positive infinity.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Almost.   The pdf equals one over those two intervals, and zero *anywhere* else.   (ie: Not just between them.) $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 &:& (0\leq x < 0.5) \vee(1.5\leq x< 2)\\ 0 &:& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

This is a uniform continuous distribution over the interval $[0;0.5)\cup[1.5;2)$

(b) That is *not* the formula for expectation of a *continuous* random variable with density function $f(x)$.   Regardless, you should be able to establish the expectation of the random variable by inspecting the graph.

(c) The event $\lbrace \omega\in\Omega : X(\omega)\in(0.6;0.65]\rbrace$ is also know as the event of: $0.6<X\leq 0.65$.   Either by inspecting the graph, or from the probability density function you should be able to determine the probability that the random variable may be within this interval.

(d) A cumulative distribution function has certain properties.   Does this graph satisfy all of them?   List them and check.